# Simplest Non-Abelian Example of Two Isomorphic Direct Products $A\times B$ and $A \times C$ for which $B$ is not isomorphic to $C$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we have two groups $ A \times B$ and $A \times C$ which are isomorphic to each other, but $B$ is not isomorphic to $C$. Can you find **non-abelian** groups $A,B$, and $C$ satisfying these criteria? The simpler the example, the better, but I am also curious about more contrived examples, as well.

I failed to come up with any non-abelian examples and could only come up with abelian ones. Can you come up with any?

Comment: Take any group $G$, take infinite direct product $A=\prod_i G$. Then $A\times G = A\times 1$.

Comment: I like this example. The only thing I don't like about it is that the trivial group is abelian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick any nonabelian group $G$ with $G\not\cong G\times G$. Then take $A=\prod_{i\in\omega} G$, $B=G$, $C=G\times G$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_0$, $B_0$, $C_0$ be Abelian groups such that $A_0\times B_0\cong A_0\times C_0$ while $B_0\not\cong C_0$. Let $D$ be a centerless non-Abelian group, e.g., $D=S_3$. Let $A=A_0\times D$, $B=B_0\times D$, $C=C_0\times D$. Then $A$, $B$, $C$ are non-Abelian groups, and $A\times B\cong A\times C$, but $B\not\cong C$, since the center of $B$ is isomorphic to $B_0$ while the center of $C$ is isomorphic to $C_0$.

**Alternatively,** let $A$ be a non-Abelian group such that $A\cong A\times D$ for some non-trivial group $D$; let $B$ be a non-Abelian group such that $B\not\cong D\times B$, e.g. any finite non-Abelian group; and let $C=D\times B$. Then $A$, $B$, $C$ are non-Abelian groups, and $B\not\cong C$, but $A\times B\cong(A\times D)\times B\cong A\times(D\times B)\cong A\times C$. (Here, if $G$ is a non-Abelian group such that $G\not\cong G\times G$, then, taking $A=G^\infty$ and $D=B=G$, we get the example in Arturo Magidin's answer.)